# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS freezing & not using all mem

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, ram

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS for a while for working from home. I have had patience before, however I am tired of the OS freezing every 30 seconds when I am just browsing the web.

I have a Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-core Processor. and 8GB of Memory
I have dual boot with windows 10, 2x 128GB(1 for windows 10 oS & 1 for ubuntu) & a 4TB HDD which is only allocated for Windows 10, as 128GB is more than enough for my work.

I have been watching my memory for the last 10 minutes and have this currently.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7972        3348         114         103        4509        4224
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

Whenever I freeze I notice that the 'free' section is always low, and my available memory is not changing one bit.

I was wondering if it is this that is causing my machine to freeze and if I can fix it by allocating more memory to Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu manages your available RAM by handing off 4,509 KB to buffers and cache so your PC runs as fast as it can; if it needs that RAM, it will reallocate some of that cache and buffer to the processes which need it. Instead, I'd look at updating to a newer kernel by going from 18.04.1 to 18.04.3 http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/08/upgrade-ubuntu18-04-3-kernel-5-0-xorg/